# QGIS: Finding and tagging polygons inside a larger polygon

Tags: qgis

I have two sets of polygons in shapefiles.  One set of polygons is composed of a full and exclusive set of smaller polygons.  But the smaller polygons are not tagged as which larger polygon they were used to build.  Is there a way in QGIS to determine which smaller polygons make up the larger polygons and tag the smaller polygons with the ID of the larger polygon that is belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

I found the correct command in QGIS.  Vector-->Geoprocessing Tools-->Intersection.  Set the larger polygons as the Input Layer and the smaller polygons as the Output Layer.